# Nexus 4 wont hold charge after screen and battery replacement

Tags: battery, charging, nexus-4

I've just replaced my broken screen and put a new battery into my nexus 4 following this you tube vid:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AZDAIgwbXk4.

When I first plugged in the charger (1A generic usb charger) The battery level dropped to critical and the "connect your charger" message popped up about 20 times per second.  I turned it off and plugged in the charger but it wont charge.  It displays the battery charging graphic, but the battery never takes in charge.

I thought it might be a dud battery so I replaced it with another new battery.

The new battery charged once successfully, (and here I was thinking that I had pulled my home repair off that this point and was just about to break out the champagne and celebrate!)

I just plugged in the charger and the phone did the same thing.  Lost the charge, flashed the 'connect your charger' pop up a zillion times per second, and now again, it wont hold any charge.

Any ideas on what I can do?

Any and all help *much* appreciated!

Bruce.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you prob got a new phone by now or fixed it.

But if you say the `"The new battery charged once successfully"` you mean you were able to charge it only with the phone off?

If so, sounds like you might have had a short circuit somewhere near the battery's USB port connection, and only occurs when a certain circuit is on due to the phone being on. Or it could be just something is loose... hard to tell from the details given.

What I'd do is try and take it apart again and see if anything got damaged or loose around that area.

Gotta keep in mind these devices are very delicate and use low voltages. You gotta do fixes like this as if they were "surgery" and take all precautions, proper tools, etc. A bit of static electricity discharging from your hand or even damaging the track in the board somehow can cause big time damage. Tiny transistors are easily damaged by static electricity so always wear a [anti-static wriststrap](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00004Z5D1) when doing these repairs.

Let us know what happened!?

Comment: One can also replace the USB flex/USB connector board and see if that fixed the issue.